# How to add action?

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

Can I add 2 actions for a UIBarButtonItem?
First, I'm using a UIBarButtonItem. It looks like.

```
 button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"hoge"
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                          target:self
                                          action:@selector(method)];
```

Next, I want to add it action.
How to add action?

Comment: For `UIBarButtonItem` you can not.  You could only set/reset.

Answer (score 2):

You cant add more actions to `UIBarButton`, but to `UIButton` you can:

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(action1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(action2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(action3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

UIBarButtonItem* barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```